# How does bodyParser know which view to populate in to req.body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, body-parser

In the code below, we have a single view viz. `fruitPicker.html` so there is no ambiguity with regards to how bodyParser should populate `req.body`

app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , cons = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);


// Handler for internal server errors
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.message);
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500);
  res.render('error_template', {error: err});
}

app.use(errorHandler);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('fruitPicker', {
    'fruits' : ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach']
  });
});

app.post('/favorite_fruit', function(req,res,next) {
  var favorite = req.body.fruit;
  if (typeof favorite == 'undefined') {
    next(Error('Please choose a fruit!'));
  }
  else {
    res.send("Your favorite fruit is " + favorite);
  }
});

app.listen(3030);
console.log('Express server listening on port 3030');
```

fruitPicker.html:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Fruit Picker</title></head>
  <body>
    <form action="/favorite_fruit" method="POST">
      <p>What is your favorite fruit?</p>
      {% for fruit in fruits %}
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="{{fruit}}">{{fruit}}</input>
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<!doctype HTML>
```

What if we had several views, say `fruitPicker.html` and `drinksPicker.html`? I suppose `bodyParser` would then populate `req.body` from the currently latest view we're coming from, is that correct? How do we then communicate this information to `app.post` so that post can return a different response based on each (Your favorite fruit is ... or Your favorite drink is ...)? We only had a generic variable `req.body` which doesn't differentiate between fruits and drinks so how would `app.post` know? Is it only up to us naming the radio boxes different names and assigning either `req.body.fruit` or `req.body.drink` to favorite? This seems not very robust because we could have instances where we inadvertently have same names for the input radio boxes (they are in different files after all) and could make for hard debugging, no? It's better if bodyParser built in the back-tracked path it came from, no?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
   for(var x in req.body){
      if(x=='fruit'){
        res.send("Your favorite fruit is " + req.body[x] );
      }
    else if(x=='drink'){
        res.send("Your favorite drink is " + req.body[x] );
      }
}
```

Comment: what is 'x' referring to? the name attribute of the input?

Comment: Yes. It refers to the name of the input field.

Comment: in the OP, I mentioned that this is not very robust. Surely these must be a feature whereby bodyParser is able to track which view the action is coming from. I looked at the docs but could not find the variable through which this is passed.